# Determine all triples (a,b,c) of positive integers for which ab−c,bc−a, and ca−b are powers of 2

Tags: nt.number-theory

Determine all triples $(a, b, c)$ of positive integers for which $a b-c, b c-a$, and $c a-b$ are powers of $2 .$

Explanation, I realized that a power of 2 is an integer of the form $2^{n}$, where $n$ denotes some nonnegative integer, but I can't solve it as well

Comment: This was Problem 2 in the International Mathematical Olympiad 2015. The only solutions are $(2, 2, 2)$, $(2, 2, 3)$, $(2, 6, 11)$ and $(3, 5, 7)$ and permutations. A short solution solution can be found here: https://web.evanchen.cc/exams/IMO-2015-notes.pdf. The question was also answered on Math Stackexchange here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1356164/finding-a-b-c-with-ab-c-bc-a-and-ca-b-being-powers-of-2.

Answer (score 2):

For what it is worth, here is my own solution.

We will show that the solutions are $(2,2,2)$, $(2,2,3)$, $(2,6,11)$, $(3,5,7)$, and their permutations. These are clearly solutions, so we only need to show that there are no other solutions.

By assumption, with some $l,m,n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$ we have
\begin{equation}\tag{1}
ab-c=2^l,\qquad bc-a=2^m,\qquad ca-b=2^n.
\end{equation}

Assume first that $a$, $b$, $c$ are not distinct, say $a=b$. Then $(1)$ simplifies to
$$a^2-c=2^l,\qquad a(c-1)=2^m,$$
hence $a=2^r$ and $c-1=2^s$ for some $r,s\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$. Therefore, $2^{2r}=a^2=c+2^l=1+2^s+2^l$, which forces by the uniqueness of the binary expansion that either $s=0$ and $l=1$, or $l=0$ and $s=1$. Hence $a=b=2$, and $c=2$ or $c=3$.

Assume now that $a$, $b$, $c$ are distinct. By adding and subtracting the equations under $(1)$ in pairs, we get
\begin{equation}\tag{2}
(b-1)(c+a)=2^m+2^l,\ \ (c-1)(a+b)=2^n+2^m,\ \ (a-1)(b+c)=2^l+2^n;
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
(b+1)(c-a)=2^m-2^l,\ \ (c+1)(a-b)=2^n-2^m,\ \ (a+1)(b-c)=2^l-2^n.
\end{equation}
In particular, $a,b,c\geq 2$ by $(2)$. Hence, without loss of generality, $2\leq a<b<c$, and then $l<n<m$ by $(3)$.

From $(2)$ it follows that $b+c\leq 2^l+2^n\leq 3\cdot 2^{n-1}$, hence also that $b<3\cdot 2^{n-2}$ and $b+a<3\cdot 2^{n-1}$. In particular, $b-a$ is not divisible by $2^n$, and then $(3)$ shows that $c$ is odd. Clearly, either $4\nmid c-1$ or $4\nmid c+1$, hence from $(2)$ and $(3)$ it follows that $b-a$ or $b+a$ is divisible by $2^{n-1}$.
That is, $b\in\{2^{n-1}-a,2^{n-1}+a,2^n-a\}$. In either case we have $2^{n-1}\leq a+b$, whence by $(2)$,
$$(a-1)(b+c)=2^l+2^n\leq 3\cdot 2^{n-1}\leq 3(a+b)<3(b+c).$$
Comparing the two sides, we infer that $a=2$ or $a=3$. Moreover, in the case of $a=3$, the last bound even yields $b+c\leq 3\cdot 2^{n-2}$, so that $b<3\cdot 2^{n-3}$ and $b+a<3\cdot 2^{n-2}$. So in this case $b=2^{n-1}-a$ is the only choice for $b$.

If $a=2$, then $2b-c=2^l$ is odd, i.e. $l=0$. Then, from $(1)$ we get that $2^n+b=2c=2(2b-1)$, i.e. $2^n+2=3b$.
Using that $b\in\{2^{n-1}-2,2^{n-1}+2,2^n-2\}$, we get one increasing triple $a<b<c$ in this case, namely $(a,b,c)=(2,6,11)$.

If $a=3$, then $b=2^{n-1}-3$, and from $(1)$ we get $c=(2^n+b)/3=2^{n-1}-1$. Therefore in $(1)$ we also have $2^l=3b-c=2^n-8$, which forces $l=3$ and $n=4$. So in this case $(a,b,c)=(3,5,7)$.